# Can't send emojis in subject when sending mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, unicode, phpmailer, emoji, subject

My PHPMailer relevant options are configured like this:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mailer->isHTML(true);
```

Then, if i try to send an email to my hotmail.com account, with some emojis in the subject field like this:

```
$foo = "\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5 text \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5";
$mail->Subject = $foo;
$mail->Body = "<p style='font-size:100px'>Mail body: $foo</p>";
```

The mail is sent ok and the word "text" surrounded by two little fire emojis appears correctly in the email subject. The mail body appears correctly also:

[image]

. If i try this:

```
$foo = "\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5 text text \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5";
$mail->Subject = $foo;
$mail->Body = "<p style='font-size:100px'>Mail body: $foo</p>";
```

again subject and body appears correctly:

[image]

but if i add another "text" word:

```
$foo = "\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5 text text text \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5";
$mail->Subject = $foo;
$mail->Body = "<p style='font-size:100px'>Mail body: $foo</p>";
```

then this happens:

[image]

so the subject emojis are replaced with 4 question marks each (the 4 bytes comprising the emoji unicode character maybe?)

What is happening?

Comment: If you look at the raw message that you received what does the subject header look like?

Comment: @Sammitch do you refer to this one?: `Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?ðÿ¥_text_text_text_ðÿ¥?=` .For completion the first email (the one with just one "text" word) has this one: `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?8J+UpSB0ZXh0IPCflKU=?=` and the second mail (the one with two "text" words) has this one: `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?8J+UpSB0ZXh0IHRleHQg8J+UpQ==?=`

Comment: That first one is not at all correct. I've taken a peek through the PHPMailer source and found that it will switch between base64 and quoted-printable based on whichever is shortest and "least likely to break" and it still does this correctly and shouldn't produce that bad output. I would suggest sending a test email to a different provider [eg: gmail] and see if it still happens.

Comment: @Sammitch I have investigated the PHPMailer source too and as you say it changes the subject header encoding from base64 to "q enconding" when some specific bytes are found in the subject (some of the emoji bytes are amogst them) and the subject's length exceeds some limit (that happens with 3 "text" words). That "q enconding" makes hotmail (or gmail, i have tested it) to misunderstand the subject header i guess. Should i report this issue somehow?.

Comment: Any news on this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was just one provider or the other I'd say it was them, but *both* feels unlikely. I would wager that it's something on the sending end like an outbound filter that's improperly mangling the header. While you can specify the charset and encoding for the *body* of an email, the headers *must* be 7-bit safe, so if you want to use a fancier charset it has to follow the format specified in [RFC1342](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1342.txt).

I would wager that there's something in the outbound mail infrastructure that's decoding, and then incorrectly *re*-encoding the subject header. I would suggest contacting the administrators of your outbound mailing service and/or testing through another provider.

In the meantime, you can manually encode the subject line yourself, as the PHPMailer code shouldn't kick in unless it detects a non-7bit-safe character. eg:

```
function encode_subject($subject, $charset, $force=false) {
    if( !$force && $subject === quoted_printable_encode($subject) ) {
        return $subject;
    }
    return sprintf('=?%s?Q?%s?=', $charset, quoted_printable_encode($subject));
}
```